# Recyclerview fragment

Tags: android

E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout

i am getting this error when trying to get info from my localhost db into my tabbed activity using a recyclerview, i know this question has been answered i just want someone to see my code.

```
    public class Clients extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewExample";
    final String url ="http://192.168.202.112:443/lawfirmdb/get_client.php";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<FeedItem> feedsList;
    MyRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    View view;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_CLIENT = "clients";
    private static final String TAG_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
    private static final String TAG_LAST_NAME = "last_name";


    public Clients() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        feedsList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clients, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        downloadClients();
        return view;

    }

    public void downloadClients() {
        new ClientRetriver().execute(url);
    }

    class ClientRetriver extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

            Integer success = 0;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                // 200 represents HTTP OK
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    parseResult(response.toString());
                    success = 1; // Successful

                } else {
                    success = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            return success;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
            // Download complete. Let us update UI

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (success == 1) {


               adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), feedsList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        private void parseResult(String success) {
            try {
                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(success);
                JSONArray clients = response.optJSONArray("clients");
                //feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < clients.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject post = clients.optJSONObject(i);
                    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                    item.setFirst_name(post.optString("first_name"));
                    item.setLast_name(post.optString("last_name"));

                    feedsList.add(item);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

my adapter is:

        public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {enter code here
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, null);

        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
        FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

        //Download image using picasso library
     /*   Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getThumbnail())
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(customViewHolder.imageView);
*/
        //Setting text view title
        customViewHolder.ClientName.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getFirst_name()));
        customViewHolder.ClientNumber.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getLast_name()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        protected TextView ClientName,ClientNumber;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.ClientName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.client_name);
            this.ClientNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.client_number);
        }

    }
```

this is my logcat output

```
               03-07 10:21:53.397    1768-1768/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-07 10:21:53.609    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-07 10:21:53.612    1768-1768/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42e7870, tid 1768
03-07 10:21:53.629    1768-1768/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
03-07 10:21:54.284    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-07 10:21:54.296    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-07 10:21:54.308    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-07 10:21:54.322    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf039480, tid 1813
03-07 10:21:54.431    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-07 10:21:54.485    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-07 10:21:54.499    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-07 10:21:54.499    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf035780, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-07 10:21:54.516    1768-1768/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-07 10:21:55.618    1768-1768/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-07 10:22:01.554    1768-1768/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
03-07 10:22:01.698    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-07 10:22:01.698    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb436ddc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-07 10:22:02.343    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-07 10:22:02.343    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb436de00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-07 10:22:02.373    1768-1813/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant V/RenderScript﹕ 0xb41a7000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
```

this is my new logcat out after adding the blank adapter in onCreate

```
        03-08 04:51:11.039  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb439bd40, tid 10473
03-08 04:51:11.056  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-08 04:51:11.077  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-08 04:51:11.094  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-08 04:51:11.094  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43e1120, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-08 04:51:11.351      753-779/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant/.activities.MainActivity: +3s265ms
03-08 04:51:11.650      753-824/system_process D/TaskPersister﹕ removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=152_task.xml
03-08 04:51:18.306      753-811/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
03-08 04:51:18.329     753-1020/system_process V/WindowManager﹕ not Base app: Adding window Window{39534f2d u0 com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant.activities.MainActivity} at 3 of 8
03-08 04:51:18.351  10429-10532/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant D/RecyclerViewExample﹕ Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
03-08 04:51:18.410  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-08 04:51:18.410  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2121380, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-08 04:51:18.626     753-1338/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2a42b129 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@3789560a
03-08 04:51:18.698  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-08 04:51:18.698  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2036480, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-08 04:51:18.787  10429-10473/com.example.dennism501.lawfirmofficeassistant V/RenderScript﹕ 0xb41ac400 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
```

Comment: are you getting success from url?

Comment: no, but if i run the php script its returning the results in the browser

Comment: please upload your log file

Comment: this is my logcat out

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because your this condition never setisfied

```
if (success == 1) {


               adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), feedsList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an adapter first and then update data once it is loaded.

**1. Set Empty Adapter**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    feedsList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clients, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), feedsList));
    downloadClients();
    return view;

}
```

**2. Update Adapter in Post Execute**

```
if (success == 1) {
           adapter.updateFeedList(feedLists);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

**3. Put this Method inside your adapter**

```
public void updateFeedList(List<feedItem> feedList){
    if(feedItemList==null)
        feedItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    feedItemList.addAll(feedList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I hope it will work for you.